# Can't install Provisioning Profile on Ipad

Tags: ios, ipad

I followed all the necessary steps and created development provisioning profile. 
Im on win7, I add myapp.mobileprovision to the Itunes library file/add file to library... then I press sync.

Now when I go to settings/general on the Ipad - I dont see any profiles.

What could be the problem here. I don't get any notifications either.

Comment: You mention in a comment to Caleb that your iPhone has a profile successfully configured; was this done through the same methods you are going through now (iTunes on Windows 7)?

Comment: Still on the IPad settings/general I dont see any profiles, although IPhone configuration utility http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1466 is showing the correct profile. I just compiled my app and installed it on IPad, so all is working.
Maybe that profile info shouldn't even be displayed on the IPad...

Answer (score 1):

What type of provision profile are we talking about? Unless it's a distribution profile from an enterprise developer account, the profile needs to include the device ID for each device. If your iPad's device ID isn't included in the profile then the profile won't install on the device.

Comment: Its a development profile. Another thing - its not showing in settings/general on IPad, but on the IPhone configuration utility it is

Comment: @Caleb Thank you, good sir.  Saved me hours of pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 0):

I was digging the same issue; I have got two iPads in front of me, one of them (8.0) is not showing "Profiles" under Settings/General. On my iPad with iOS7.1.1, I can still see profiles.

The "Profiles" menu is hidden on iOS8, which handles the profiles automatically, removing the expired ones.

For more info, see: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/150432